# random distribution/probability

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers with $a \le b$, and let $X$ be a random variable that takes as values, with equal probability, the powers of $2$ in the interval $[2^a, 2^b]$. The question is asking for the expected value and the variance of $X$.

Thanks alot for the help~

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Find", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: There are $b-a+1$  equally likely possibilities for $X$. So for the expectation we multiply the sum $2^a+2^{a+1}+\cdots+2^b$ by $\frac{1}{b-a+1}$. You are probably expected to simplify the sum, perhaps by using the formula for the sum of a geometric series. For the variance, first find $E(X^2)$.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate expected value of a random variable from definition? Just for clarification, as I feel a bit slow today: are you saying that the probability distribution for $X$ is a uniform distribution on the interval [$2^a,2^b$]?

Comment: sorry for unclear question but actually the main problem is I couldn't understand what are the question actually asking. But I think yes, the probability distribution X should be on the interval [2a,2b]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values possible are $\{ 2^a, 2^{a+1}, \dots, 2^b \}$ and they all have the same probability. There are $ b -a +1$ values possible.

Thus the expectation of $X$ is:

$$ \frac{\sum_{k = a}^b 2^k}{b-a+1} = 2^a\frac{2^{b-a+1} - 1}{2-1}\frac{1}{b-a+1} =  \frac{2^{b+1} - 2^a}{b-a+1}$$

Comment: Hi Tantto, may I know how to obtain the middle part from 1st part? is there a general equation for such derivation?

Comment: This is the general formula of the sum of the terms of a geometric series:

$$ \sum_{k = a}^b {c^k} = c^a \frac{c^{b -a +1} - 1}{c - 1}$$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum for more details.