# Expected value and variance of a RV that takes values uniformly between [2^a, 2^b]

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

Similarly to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387896/random-distribution-probability/1387935) I have a question about the problem:

*"Let a and b be positive integers with $a \leq b$, and let $X$ be a random variable that takes as values, with equal probability, the powers of $2$ in the interval $[2^a, 2^b]$. Find the expected value and the variance of X.*"

I'm aware that $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{k=a}^{b} \frac{1}{b - a + 1} 2^k = \frac{2^{b+1} - 2^a}{b - a + 1}$$ and I also derived it for myself.

But from the master solution, I don't understand how the second moment $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ is derived:

$$ \mathbb{E}[X^2] = \sum_{k=a}^{b} \frac{1}{b - a + 1} (2^k)^2 = \frac{4^{b+1} - 4^a}{3(b - a + 1)}$$

Specifically: why do we need to multiply the denominator with 3 instead of just dividing by their differences $b - a + 1$ once? Since we're only squaring the random variable $X$ and there are no terms that rely on the index $k$ in the fraction, we should basically be able to move it out of the sum and just multiply the whole sum with $\frac{1}{b - a + 1}$, i.e: 
$$ \frac{1}{b - a + 1} \sum_{k=a}^{b}(2^k)^2 $$

So I was hoping someone could enlighten me on where that multiplicative factor comes from!

Comment: Since you're summing $4^a+4^{a+1}+\cdots + 4^b$ can't you just use geometric series? $4^a(1+4+16+\cdots + 4^{b-a})=\frac{4^{b+1}-4^a}{3}$

Comment: Most likely! But with my limited math knowledge, I actually don't know how this $4^a(1 + 4 + 16 ... + 4^{b - a}) = \frac{4^{b+1} - 4^a}{3}$  is derived. Again I'm not sure where the division with 3 comes from?

Comment: Read quasi’s answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recalling the identity
$$1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$
and noting that $(2^k)^2=4^k$, we get
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=a}^{b}(2^k)^2\\[4pt]
=\;&\sum_{k=a}^{b}4^k\\[4pt]
=\;&4^a\sum_{k=0}^{b-a}4^k\\[4pt]
=\;&4^a\left(\frac{4^{b-a+1}-1}{4-1}\right)\\[4pt]
=\;&\frac{4^{b+1}-4^a}{3}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Ahh okay, I wasn't actually aware of that identity. A quick google search led me to a couple of places that says: $1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^n = \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1 - x}$. So is this basically the same thing? And may I ask how you go from the one to the other?

Comment: @VanTheMan: Multiply top and bottom by $-1$.

Comment: @VanTheMan: To understand why it works, expand the product $(x-1)(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n)$.

Comment: Ahh yea it makes sense now - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Moving $\frac1{b-a+1}$ out of the sum is correct. Now rewrite $(2^k)^2$ as $4^k$ and view the sum as a number in base $4$:
$$\sum_{k=a}^b4^k=111\dots111000\dots000$$
with $b+1$ total digits and $a$ zeros. This suggests $4^{b+1}-4^a$ as a closed form, but
$$4^{b+1}-4^a=333\dots333000\dots000$$
which is the previous sum multiplied by $3$. So the division by $3$ comes in here.